# nicEditor add/remove icons using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, editor, nicedit

I have tried to add a rich text editor to my application. I'm using [nicEdit](http://nicedit.com/index.php).

```
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
  nicEditors.editors.push(new nicEditor().panelInstance(document.getElementById('single_answer_description')));
});
```

I added this part to convert my normal textarea to a richtext editor. It looks fine:

[image]

What I want to do now is to only show some of the icons like `B`, `I`, `U`. I don't want all the icons. How can I hide those? I also want to set font family by default inside the rich text editor content.

I tried to search so many links but I couldn't get any proper solution for this issue. Please help me to get out of this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the documentation](http://wiki.nicedit.com/w/page/515/Configuration%20Options)

You can add an array of the buttons you want when you instantiate the object.

```
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
  nicEditors.editors.push(
    new nicEditor({buttonList:['bold','italic']}).panelInstance(document.getElementById('single_answer_description')));
});
```

Comment: Yeah joe. right And I want to make font family by default inside nicEditor whatever may be my font family inside body once paste it will need to change font family to the default way

Comment: That will be a completely additional piece of code which I believe warrants a separate question.